# Can iPhone SDK accesses bandwidth usage data for an Application session?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, bandwidth

I want to keep statistics of bandwidth used in an application when the application is used. Is there any way in iPhone SDK to do it (or I should go to lower level, keep logging of all network requests)?